# Split string in SQL without function - including other values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've tried to find a solution that does this...I need to split a string that is in a column, to produce one entry per value, retaining the existing column values.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #SplitMeUp(
SomeInt INT NOT NULL
, SomeName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
, LongList VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #SplitMeUp VALUES (1,'First', 'A,B,C,D')
INSERT INTO #SplitMeUp VALUES (2,'Second', 'B,C,D,E,F,G')
INSERT INTO #SplitMeUp VALUES (3,'Third', 'A')
INSERT INTO #SplitMeUp VALUES (4,'Fourth', 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G')

SELECT * FROM #SplitMeUp

1   First   A,B,C,D
2   Second  B,C,D,E,F,G
3   Third   A
4   Fourth  A,B,C,D,E,F,G
```

I am trying to achieve the following, but I can't use a function as I don't have permissions, on 2012 so can't use `STRING_SPLIT` and the solutions I have found just split the actual string, not retain the other values.

```
1   First   A
1   First   B
1   First   C
1   First   D
2   Second  B
2   Second  C
2   Second  D
2   Second  E
2   Second  F
2   Second  G
3   Third   A
4   Fourth  A
4   Fourth  B
4   Fourth  C
4   Fourth  D
4   Fourth  E
4   Fourth  F
4   Fourth  G
```

Comment: Google:  `SQL Server split`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: @GordonLinoff - There are just a few results returned for that!

Comment: As a side note, in general this type of relationship is naturally implemented in Relational Algebra with a one-to-many relationship between the initial table and a variable number of values in a separate table. If distinct values can be associated with more than one tuple in the initial table a many-to-many relationship could be created to achieve this.

Comment: @BartHofland  - Y.S. has already given that answer.

Comment: I see. Strange. I didn't place that as a comment. So I removed it. I only flagged your question as a duplicate. Seems that the comment was somehow added automatically?